# ¿Cómo hago un menú para seleccionar opciones con Bash?

Tags: linux, bash, script, while, shell

Lo que busco es que si se pulsa algún número el cual no tenga asignado ninguna función entonces se vuelva a ejecutar el case y me diga de nuevo las opciones y que esto se haga con un while o un for.

El problema es que no sé cómo aplicarlo. Este es mi código actual:

```
case $OPCION in 

        1) echo "Has elegido detener el contenedor $CONT " 
                detener_maquina
        ;;

        2) echo "Has elegido iniciar el contenedor $CONT " 
                iniciar_maquina 
        ;;

        3) echo "Has elegido gestionar la RAM del contenedor $CONT "
                gestion_ram
        ;;

        4) echo "Has elegido gestionar la CPU del contenedor $CONT"
                gestion_cpu
        ;;
        *) echo "Opcion no valida. Detenido el script" 
                exit;;

esac

done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para hacer un menú de selección puedes usar `select`:

```
PS3="Elige tu opción: "
opciones=("detener" "iniciar" "ram" "cpu" "salir")
select opt in "${opciones[@]}"
do
    case $opt in 

        "detener") echo "Has elegido detener el contenedor $CONT " 
                detener_maquina; break
        ;;

        "iniciar") echo "Has elegido iniciar el contenedor $CONT " 
                iniciar_maquina; break
        ;;

        "ram") echo "Has elegido gestionar la RAM del contenedor $CONT "
                gestion_ram; break
        ;;

        "cpu") echo "Has elegido gestionar la CPU del contenedor $CONT"
                gestion_cpu; break
        ;;
        "salir") break 2
        ;;
        *) echo "Opcion no válida."
    esac
done
```

Cuando lo ejecutes verás algo así como:

```
$ bash mi_script.sh
1) detener
2) iniciar
3) ram
4) cpu
5) salir
Elige tu opción:
```

E interactuarás así:

```
$ bash mi_script.sh
1) detener
2) iniciar
3) ram
4) cpu
5) salir
Elige tu opción: 1
Has elegido detener el contenedor  
$ bash mi_script.sh
1) detener
2) iniciar
3) ram
4) cpu
5) salir
Elige tu opción: 5
$ bash mi_script.sh
1) detener
2) iniciar
3) ram
4) cpu
5) salir
Elige tu opción: 7
Opcion no válida.
```

Comment: @ffedorqui 'SO deja de dañar' gracias, por ayudarme me ha servido de mucho, ahora me funciona perfectamente y como queria.

Comment: Qué bien, me alegra mucho haber sido de ayuda, @ShiroMB